# How to get a specific ListItem from Menu Component in MUI for React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, menu

I have a List that has several ListItems which I get from an array, let's call it `myCollection`. Each ListItem has a MenuIcon which opens a Menu, showing an option to delete the item. The simplified code looks like this:

```js
<List>
  <Menu
    open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
    anchorEl={anchorEl}
    ...>
      <MenuItem onClick={() => handleDelete(⚡collectionItem)}>Delete</MenuItem>
  </Menu>

  {myCollection.map((collectionItem) => (
    <ListItem secondaryAction={
      <IconButton onClick={(e) => setAnchorEl(e.currentTarget)}>
        <MoreVertIcon />
      </IconButton>
    }>
      {collectionItem.name}
    </ListItem>
  )}
</List>
```

My problem is that I need to know which item in `myCollection` was selected to pass it to the delete function. However, I don't have a reference to the current collectionItem in the `myCollection` array from the Menu. Moving the Menu into the map function makes no sense because multiple menus would be rendered. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by giving the `IconButton`s custom [HTML data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), e.g.

```js
<IconButton data-collection-id={collection.id} onClick={...}>
...
</IconButton>
```

Then, in the onClick function, we can retrieve it by using `event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-collection-id")`.